# Can we modify an element of a defined matrix function?

Tags: matrix

Let us define a matrix funtion:
`f[x_]:={{x,1},{x^2},1}}`
then we wants to modify its elements as following

```
Part[f[x],1,2]=x^3
Part[f[x],2,1]=x
```

Can we do this?
Actually I had written a program like this and the error shows:
"f[x] in the part assignment is not a symbol."

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the DownValues of the function `f`  indirectly?  Why? what is the point of this? This produces convoluted code which will not be understood 2 days after it is written. But if you just want to modify matrix entry, then all what you have to do is `r=f[x]; r[[2,1]]=x` that is all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to do this when I need to redefine some element of a matrix where all other elements remain unchanged..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ReplacePart` on `DownValues` of `f` to make changes to the definition  of `f`:

```
DownValues[f] = ReplacePart[DownValues[f], {{1, 2, 2, 1} -> x, {1, 2, 1, 2} -> x^3}];    
f[t]
```

> {{t, t^3}, {t}, {2, 1}}

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response..

Comment: @atanu, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.